# I have a spreadsheet with a hundred groups and can't get-for/ loop to work

Tags: loops, gmail

I have the following to pull users in a gmail group. Problem is, I have a spreadsheet with like a hundred groups and can't get my traditional For/ loop to work. I need to loop through the spreadsheet, add the new group email and run again

```
    function getGroupMembers() {
      try {

        var groupEmail = 'GroupAddress@gmail.com';
        var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
        var users = group.getUsers();
        for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++){
            // do something witty with the list of users
          Logger.log(users[u].getEmail());
         }

  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error/problem you are seeing?  "It doesn't work" doesn't really help us to help you...

Comment: I stopped doing this stuff years ago and in truth I have no idea how I used to format loops. Everything I've tried has failed pretty much the same as if a child had done it, I have this: FOR /F %G IN (c:\properties.xlsx) DO

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Comment: The issue is I haven't done this in years and I do not know how to format a for loop in Google Apps AT ALL, it doesn't work means I have no for loop experience outside command line (antiquated scripting platform from the stone ages) I know it should be possible to read the users in a group, and compare them against a list which the group should have and then add them as appropriate,  Step one, reading the list of groups I don't know how to do, step 2, pulling the user list for the groups is done, Steps 3,4,5 aren't fleshed out at all yet. I just need a for loop that will work in this platform.

Comment: I need to list the users of the sub groups:

FOR /F %G IN (c:\properties.xlsx) DO
function getGroupMembers() {
  try {

    var groupEmail = 'ALbid_costco@allenlund.com';
    var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
    var users = group.getUsers();
    for (var u = 0; u < users.length; u++){
      // Would prefer to output to a .csv
      Logger.log(users[u].getEmail());
    }

  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}

Comment: then add this list of users to the appropriate Main group.

function addGroupMember() {
  var userEmail = 'user@email.com';
  var groupEmail = 'Group@email.com';
  var member = {
    email: userEmail,
    role: 'MEMBER'
  }
  member = AdminDirectory.Members.insert(member, groupEmail);
  Logger.log('User %s added as a member of group %s.', userEmail, groupEmail);
}

Both of these scripts work but I don't have a clue how to have the first one read from a list of sub groups and then output that list of users in a format that the second script could read etc.